# GNU Autotools, what is "*h.in" files?

Tags: header, gnu-make, autotools

I am new to autotools, and can't find out where from *.h.in files are created?
I am trying to create small hello_demo for my library, where I include *.h and use it. *make* throws me error, that  *h.in not found.

Any guide how to make it proper way, will be very appreciate)

Comment: You create `foo.h.in` type files manually, unlike `config.h.in`. Typically with `@SOME_VAR@` where `SOME_VAR` is defined using `AC_SUBST`, and by listing said file in `AC_CONFIG_FILES([foo.h])`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about `config.h.in`, it is generated by default by `autoheader`. You should not strictly need it though.

Make sure you're using `autoreconf -fis` to generate your autotools support files, that will call all the needed tools for the generation to work. I would also point you to my [guide](https://autotools.io/whosafraid.html) for the very minimal code you need to build a project, which does not involve `autoheader` at all.

Comment: But what about case, when I'm trying to use my library in a demo, before *make install* ? How I should properly link them with autotools?

Comment: If you're referring to `config.h.in`, you need to rebuild autotools before make.

Comment: no I just want to refer mylibrary.h in a demo app.  And  I am getting error during *make* ("No such file or folder."). Am asking  about  *.h.in files, because I see such solution in other lybrary sources.